# Not able to convert data type varchar to numeric

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have below table :

```
id  amount
12  974
11  929
9   837,5
4   606,5
```

and i have taken amount `datatype as varchar(100)`. Now when i am trying to convert into decimal then at that time it giving me conversion error.

i have written the following query:

```
select id,cast(amount as decimal(10,2)) as amount from table order by amount desc
```

With the above query i am getting error : `Error converting data type varchar to numeric.`

How can i solve this issue?

Comment: Because amount contain `,` so you can not convert into numeric. `,` (Comma )is for decimal point or need to remove ?

Comment: Is `837,5` = `837.5` ? or what ? What should happen when there is more than one comma ?

Comment: replace comma first then try to convert it

Comment: @Prdp yes this is italian format (837,5)

Comment: @deepak - Will there be more than one comma

Comment: yes. it willl be more than one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     create function [dbo].[udf_splitstring] (@tokens    varchar(max),
                                             @delimiter varchar(5))
    returns @split table (
      token varchar(200) not null )
    as
      begin
          declare @list xml

          select @list = cast('<a>'
                              + replace(@tokens, @delimiter, '</a><a>')
                              + '</a>' as xml)

          insert into @split
                      (token)
          select ltrim(t.value('.', 'varchar(200)')) as data
          from   @list.nodes('/a') as x(t)

          return
      end


 CREATE TABLE Table5
        ([id] int, [amount] varchar(100))

        INSERT INTO Table5
            ([id], [amount])
        VALUES
        (12,'974'),
        (11,'929'),
        (9 ,'837,5'),
        (4 ,'606,5')

        select id,cast(token as decimal(10,2)) as amount from Table5 
        cross apply (select token from udf_splitstring([amount], ',') )a

    id  amount
    12  974.00
    11  929.00
    9   837.00
    9   5.00
    4   606.00
    4   5.00
```

or 
2)

```
    select id,amount,cast(replace (amount,',','.' )as decimal(10,2)) as amount1  from Table5

id  amount  amount1
12  974 974.00
11  929 929.00
9   837,5   837.50
4   606,5   606.50
```

3)

```
SELECT *,
    TRY_PARSE( [amount] AS NUMERIC(10,2) USING 'El-GR' ) x
FROM Table5
```

Comment: Hi , Thanks for the answer . i think with this code amount convert from 837.5 to 837.00!!!

Comment: is this satisfied your requirement ..@deepak

Comment: Not completely as my value change from 837.5 to 837.00 .

Answer (score 0):

If the string contain comma， you can not convert to decimal directly,
you can convert the string to Money type

```
    ;WITH t(id,amount)AS(
       SELECT 12,'974' UNION
       SELECT 11,'929' UNION
       SELECT 9,'837,5.123' UNION
       SELECT 4,'606,5'
       )
    SELECT id,CONVERT(MONEY,t.amount) FROM t WHERE ISNUMERIC(t.amount)=1
```

```
id          
----------- ---------------------
4           6065.00
9           8375.123
11          929.00
12          974.00
```